# Chartboost on iOS: Not able to stop session

Tags: iphone, ios, chartboost

When you start Chartboost session with:

```
[chartBoostInstance startSession]
```

in the appDelegate,the ads start showing.

How do I stop the session if I implement an in-app purchase that removes the ad?

Lejla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link  [here](https://help.chartboost.com/documentation/ios) claims that-

> Use this Chartboost SDK delegate method to prevent interstitials until the second startSession:

```
- (BOOL)shouldRequestInterstitialsInFirstSession {
        return NO;
    }
```

Comment: thanks For selecting answer because i have very low reputation

Answer (score 0):

`[cb startSession];` only  Notify the beginning of a user session.not show the adds.you show ads by showInterstitial method

```
[cb showInterstitial];
```

so when user made in app purchase then set bool key `isPurchase` YES in your `NSUserDefaults`

and check when show ads

```
if(![userDefaults boolForKey:@"isPurchase"])
        {
             NSLog(@"Enter add start ");

           [[Chartboost sharedChartboost]  showInterstitial];
        }
        [userDefaults synchronize];

    }
```